# Using Image Tags in JSON

Tags: json, image, validation, tags

Im trying to make my image change to another image on a timer using json.
It wont work and when i try and validate the json file it keeps saying theres an error with this line:

The image "apple.png" is inside the Images folder but the error that comes up is :

< img src = Images /
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You question is unclear what exactly what you are asking because I can't see the rest of the JSON. What is probably happening is that your are using invalid characters. JSON is very strict in what it will allow (i.e. no functions or any nonprimatives).

I imagine you have something like this though:

```js
{
  img: <img src='/path/to/img'>
}
```

Instead, just send the url and set the `src` of the image tag.

```js
json = {
  url: '/path/to/img'
}

img = document.getElementById("myimg")
img.src = json.url;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its different how we use it

This is the type of JSON Code we have to use

    {
"timing" : {
                        "start" : "18"
                    },
"events":[
{
"response": "changeContent",
"elementsQuery" : "#image",
"content": <img src="Images/elm_meeting_medikit.png" width="200px;"> 
}
]
                },

I added <div id="image" > and closed the tag which is where the #image has come from in the elementsQuery.

Comment: { "timing" : { "start" : "18" }, "events":[ { "response": "changeContent", "elementsQuery" : "#image", "content": <img src="Images/elm_meeting_medikit.png" width="200px;"> } ] },

Comment: Still, you can't have HTML elements inside of a JSON; it doesn't work that way. Instead of "content", you could have "attrs" and change corresponding attributes for the selected element.